# How to export multilingual MySQL table to Excel without garbled text (e.g. à¹à¸­à¸™à¸™à)?

Tags: mysql, excel, unicode, phpmyadmin, export-to-excel

I have a MySQL table where I store text entered in any kind of language. The text is displayed correctly on the website, [example](http://scratch.mit.edu/tagged/toploved/%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%B4%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%B1%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%99) but when I export the data to Excel I get garbled text.

I tried exporting the data via PHPMyAdmin and even just doing something from the command line like mysql -user -p db < query.sql  > export.tsv  and I get  garbled text. For example instead of animación I get animaciÃ³n or instead of แอนนิเมชั่น I get à¹à¸­à¸™à¸™à¸´à¹€à¸¡à¸Šà¸±à¹ˆà¸™.

This could be a combination of factors involving Excel, MySQL and PHPMyAdmin, but I imagine others have tried to do the same.

Comment: What character set is your database / csv export?

Comment: There is a chance that your data is already corrupt in your MySQL database. Do a hex dump (ie: `SELECT HEX(column) ...` and tell us what you get (use a column that has special characters)

Answer (score 0):

Excel and Mysql support Unicode fully, but PHP (I think) doesn't have very good Unicode support, so you may be having trouble exporting from PHPMyAdmin for that reason.

Look on the web for a good mysql manager which will export data from your tables correctly in Unicode format and you should be fine.